# How to fill holes in a 3D mesh?

Tags: objects

I was wondering if there is an easy way to fill these holes in my 3D object?

I am looking for a quick method where you don't need to select every vertice on its own.
[image]

Comment: you can create a second object like a small sphere, and boolean your object with it

Comment: @moonboots Could you give some more information on which boolean you should use?

Comment: create a sphere, flatten it a bit, select your original object, give it a Boolean modifier, choose the Union option and choose the flatten sphere as boolean object, apply the modifier, rework a bit the sculpt in order to make the sphere merge correctly